# Javascript: encodeURI() / encodeURIComponent() charset

Tags: javascript, url, encoding, character-encoding

Is there any way to specify charset in Javascript's encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent()? E.g.:

`encodeURIComponent("例子", "UTF-8")` outputs `%E4%BE%8B%E5%AD%90`

`encodeURIComponent("例子", "GBK")` outputs `%C0%FD%D7%D3`

Comment: No, these functions are UTF-8 only. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Christoph, it's for a dictionary lookup script that dynamically generates links to UTF-8 and GBK pages based on user input data. Is there any functions that can do GBK encoding?

Answer (score 3):

My solution is to used a npm package [urlencode](https://github.com/node-modules/urlencode) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Write in urlencode.js:

```
var urlencode = require("urlencode");
module.exports = function (s) { return urlencode(s, "gbk"); }
```

`browserify urlencode.js --s encode > bundle.js`

And in bundle.js, a function called `encode` is declared.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [earlier edit of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/14854423/1) before you revised it, it seems like you're trying to access various Baidu Baike based on different search terms you submit. My answer is not relevant to your new JS question, but the simple solution to your old problem (and would obviate the need for a JS solution) is to specify the character encoding in the Baidu Baike URL: `&enc=`. All the following resolve correctly:

- [http://baike.baidu.com/search/word?word=例子&pic=1&sug=1&enc=utf8](http://baike.baidu.com/search/word?word=%E4%BE%8B%E5%AD%90&pic=1&sug=1&enc=utf8)
- http://baike.baidu.com/search/word?word=%E4%BE%8B%E5%AD%90&pic=1&sug=1&enc=utf8
- http://baike.baidu.com/search/word?word=%C0%FD%D7%D3&pic=1&sug=1&enc=GBK

Comment: Thank you, this really works with the Baidu. But I still wonder if there is a general and simple way to do it using JS or maybe plain HTML.

Comment: Sorry for the much belated update @kleopatra! Hope it's easier to read now. Two years later, links still resolve properly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const _encodeURIComponent = (x) =>
    x   
        .split('')
        .map((y) => {
            if (!RegExp(/^[\x00-\x7F]*$/).test(y)) {
                return iconv
                    .encode(y, encoding)
                    .reduce((a, b) => a + '%' + b.toString(16), '') 
                    .toUpperCase();
            } else {
                return y;
            }   
        })  
        .join('');
```

Replace `encoding` with desired encoding